# i need to add two variables together for a messagebox/textbox for a programming project IN C#

Tags: c#

hey all so I'm having a hard time with my code when trying to display in a `textbox`.. testing goes well till i try something along the lines of a start time being a higher number than the end time   when i do it displays something like this on my program -04-30 but on the example program it shows -0430.

How can i get it to display properly?

My last three lines of code read. (this is for a programming project for my college class. i have my form program i have developed and then an example one.  for the program it asks to give a start time, and end time. and the program calculates a new arrival time due to construction in the area(which makes the original trip 25% longer)

```
int endTimeHours = (int) totalTimeMins / DIVISOR_SIXTY;
int endTimeMins = (int)totalTimeMins - (endTimeHours * DIVISOR_SIXTY);
```

//display answer in textbox for user to see and understand.

```
textBoxNewArrival.Text = string.Format("{0:d2}" + "{1:d2}", endTimeHours, endTimeMins);
```

entire code is;
`// Declare Constants
            const int HUNDRED = 100, DIVISOR_SIXTY = 60;
            const double CONSTRUCTION = 1.25;

```
        //get start time from user
        int startTime = int.Parse(textBoxStart.Text);

        //get end time from user
        int endTime = int.Parse(textBoxEnd.Text);

        //separate and convert to hours and minutes for start time
        int hoursStart = startTime / HUNDRED;
        int minsStart = startTime % HUNDRED;
        int totalMinutesStart = (hoursStart * DIVISOR_SIXTY) + minsStart;

        //separate and convert to hours and minutes for end time
        int hoursEnd = endTime / HUNDRED;
        int minEnd = endTime % HUNDRED;
        int totalMinutesEnd = (hoursEnd * DIVISOR_SIXTY) + minEnd;

        //find total duration by subtracting total end times in minutes from total start time in minutes
        int totalDuration = totalMinutesEnd - totalMinutesStart;

        //take the totalDuration or time between start and end and multiply by 1.25 for construction time.
        double construction = totalDuration * CONSTRUCTION;

        //take totalmintuesstart from begining and add construction.
        double totalTimeMins = totalMinutesStart + construction;

        //find and convert the answers into hours and minutes total
        int endTimeHours = (int) totalTimeMins / DIVISOR_SIXTY;
        int endTimeMins = (int) totalTimeMins - (endTimeHours * DIVISOR_SIXTY);




        //display answer in textbox for user to see and understand.
        textBoxNewArrival.Text = string.Format("{0:d2}" + "{1:d2]", endTimeHours, endTimeMins.ToString().Remove(0, 1));          
        `
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo, but I see wrong formatting: "{0:d2}" + "{1:d2]" instead shouldn't it be: "{0:d2}" + "{1:d2}" ?

Comment: Also if possible try using a TimeSpan with the hours & mins you calculated and can use a suitable [formatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx) to show it properly.

Comment: not sure what that means.. haha i am brand new to programming. i am in fundamentals of programming in college and this is the first class i have ever taken for it..

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution you should try doing this in the textBox assignation:

```
textBoxNewArrival.Text = string.Format("{0:d2}" + "{1:d2}", int.Parse(endTimeHours, endTimeMins.ToString().Remove(0,1)));
```

this is the test i did to check if this time worked:

```
class Forms
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int  endTimeHours = -4;;
        int endTimeMins = -30;
        string temp = string.Format("{0:d2}" + "{1:d2}", endTimeHours, int.Parse(endTimeMins.ToString().Remove(0, 1)));
        Console.WriteLine(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: the .Remove doesnt appear to be a command in this situation. i type it in by i just throws a red error lines underneath .Remove..  im in visual studio if that makes any difference?

Comment: right, sorry, you first need to add the .ToString() method :P ///////////////////////// textBoxNewArrival.Text = string.Format("{0:d2}" + "{1:d2]", endTimeHours, endTimeMins.ToString().Remove(0,1));

Comment: Right! i keep forgetting you're printing the variables as int :P

Comment: here is the code   not sure what happened(i think i might have declared data types wrong.. (also user inputs time in a 24 hour format.  i have converted to minutes and back throughout the program

Comment: look, you can add another piece of code to what i gave to you. But i don't know if it'll look too "messy" for you this way :P
in any case, just check my answer ↑↑ i just edited it in a way that should work :P

Comment: apparently you cant cast it so it has to be with te "int.Parse()" method

Comment: done, try it now. I tested it so it should work.
this time it was a typo :P i must be half asleep :P

Comment: you sure that the errors are on that line of code?
as i said, now i tested it, ill put the test i made here too.

Comment: this is the error code i get Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string, System.Globalization.NumberStyles)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Jordan\Desktop\CSN 1400\AllApps\Project03\Project03\Form1.cs 71 73 Project03

Comment: and then Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string' C:\Users\Jordan\Desktop\CSN 1400\AllApps\Project03\Project03\Form1.cs 71 83 Project03

Comment: and finally Error 3 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Globalization.NumberStyles' C:\Users\Jordan\Desktop\CSN 1400\AllApps\Project03\Project03\Form1.cs 71 97 Project03

Comment: Maybe the first error is not in that part of the code, you need to make sure that in the textBox are just numbers before making conversions to int (in the first two lines)
as to the 2nd error is weird, if you're including System namespace with the using statement then you should be able to convert from int to string. Maybe you're using one variable that is a string without using any conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the sign of the first value, and always use the absolute value of the second?

```
textBoxNewArrival.Text = string.Format("{0:d2}" + "{1:d2}", endTimeHours, Math.Abs(endTimeMins));
```

Comment: after doing this it tells me i have build errors..  would you like me to post the entire code?

Comment: Just copy and paste that line in...note that there are **two** closing parenthesis on the end; one for Math.Abs() and one for String.Format().

Comment: added entire code to original post. i think i have declared data types incorrectly throughout the program.. the last line of code though is textBoxNewArrival.Text = string.Format("{0:d2}" + "{1:d2]", endTimeHours, endTimeMins.ToString().Remove(0, 1));

Comment: That's Rick's solution, using string manipulation.  Mine is different, using Math.Abs()...look closely.

Comment: yeah i tried using that one and his as well and im continually getting build errors   not sure what i did wrong

Comment: Well...if you want **specific** help, please post the **specific** build errors and the lines they are occurring on.  Tested my code with the simplest possible setup and it works...